# Looking for cloud-to-cloud data transfer tool

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud, backup, wasabi

I need to make a backup from Wasabi bucket to Amazon S3 bucket each week. Basically, transfer data between this 2 clouds.

My current solution is to download data from a source bucket to a local directory (virtual machine), and then uploading it to the destination bucket. The problem with this approach is the cost of the intermediate step, especially for large amounts of data (Transfer the data and Save it).

Is it possible to connect two buckets directly and transfer data between them without this intermediary step? Like move files from disk to another disk in Windows 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From AWS Point of View the data transfer has to be paid, regardless which way the data is travelling.

For synchronizing [AWS DataSync](https://aws.amazon.com/datasync/) can be used, if Wasabi has a compatible interface (NFS, SMB, HDFS, S3). According to [this](https://wasabi.com/s3-compatible-cloud-storage/) Wasabi has S3 compatible interface

There are file systems that treat S3 as a file storage, but I would not advise you for that solution. They are complicated to setup and not for this use case.